# Handlebars and functions.php

Tags: php, handlebars.js

I am working on a Wordpress site that uses Handlebars. One of the functions they are using it for is to import static text assigned in the functions.php file. I tried to add a new string in the functions.php and added it's handlebars call in the handlebars template page but the new string does not seem to appear. I cannot share a link unfortunately but these are the lines of code.

**Handlebars page**

```
<p>{{req_indication}}</p>
```

**function.php**

```
function get_static_strings() {
    return Array(
        'req_indication' => "Required field",
    );
}
```

Is there something I need to add when adding a new string?

Comment: From the code, it is bit difficult to comment on the missing section if any. Please see this link https://mondaybynoon.com/handlebars-wordpress-template-parts, if it can help you fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@AmarjeetKaur Thank you for the link I did see that previously. I ended up finding the solution out I had to make changes to 1 more file and add these two lines of code to another php page.

```
$static_strings['req_indication'] = stripslashes(super_script_text(apply_filters('wpml_translate_string', $static_strings['req_indication'], "req_indication", $wpml_static_package)));

$context = array(
    'req_indication'      => $static_strings['req_indication'],);
```

I'm sure Handlebars is a great framework to use but this seemed like a lot of work to add 1 line of text.